# Flotchart with stack plugin, handling empty arrays

Tags: ajax, json, charts, stack, flot

I'm using flotchart(http://www.flotcharts.org/) with stack plugin to draw a graph containing multiples series, and i'm retrieving data from a MySQL database with a php script throught AJAX calls. The problem is that for some reasons the data of couple series may not be available or existing so MySQL will return an empty result, then the AJAX call return an empty array and this causes the chart to not draw anything after the empty serie.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
   var graph_range =10;
    var now = Math.round(+new Date()/1000) - (60*graph_range);
  var jsData = new Object();
  var d1, d2, d3  = new Object();
  $.ajaxSetup({ async: false  });
    $.getJSON('getjson.php',{id: '2', time: now, single: 'down'},function(result){ d1= result; });
    $.getJSON('getjson.php',{id: '4', time: now, single: 'down'},function(result){ d2= result; });
    $.getJSON('getjson.php',{id: '7', time: now, single: 'down'},function(result){ d3= result; });
    $.getJSON('getjson.php',{id: '8', time: now, single: 'down'},function(result){ d1= result; });
    $.getJSON('getjson.php',{id: '10', time: now, single: 'down'},function(result){ d2= result; });
    $.getJSON('getjson.php',{id: '11', time: now, single: 'down'},function(result){ d3= result; });
  $.ajaxSetup({ async: true  });
    var vals= [ d1, d2, d3];


    function plotWithOptions() {
        $.plot("#flotchart", vals , {
            series: {
                stack: true,
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    fill: true,
                    steps: 8
                }
            }
        });
    }

    plotWithOptions();
```

when i put stack to false, it works everything is drawn except the series which doesn't have data(empty array is returned); but when i turn it to "true" which i need, the very firts series are drawn but when an empty array occurs, everything after that is not drawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace

```
var vals= [ d1, d2, d3];
```

with

```
var vals = [];
if (d1 != [])
    vals.push(d1);
if (d2 != [])
    vals.push(d2);
if (d3 != [])
    vals.push(d3);
```

So only not-empty arrays are added to the plot data.

Btw: You overwrite d1, d2, d3 with the forth to sixth `getJSON` call. Is that what you want to do? You could then do without the first three `getJSON` calls since they do nothing for you.

Comment: thanks! i didn't meant to overwrite those three varible they were supposed to continue with d4, d5, d6, just a mistake of last editing, but, don't worry, in production i'm using a loop..

Comment: @Xsmael Why did you accept and later unaccept the answer? Is there still a problem?

Comment: yeah, this is not working for me, the brackets cause and error, however your post helped me to work it out, i used this condition instead `if( vals.length > 0)` and it worked!